# IBM i 7.2, Admin-Port 2004 closed

Tags: websphere, ibm-midrange

On a fresh install of IBM i 7.2, with a regular IPL, the *qhttpsvr* subsystem is started and subsequently the admin-instance, which listens on TCP Port 2001. This port immediately redirects to Port 2004 on the same machine. The Browser delivers an error. `netstat *cnn` shows that there's no open port 2004.

Short question: What am I missing on my system so Port 2004 is closed?

In *QUSRSYS/QATMHINSTC* are just two members *APACHEDFT* and *IWADFT*. Looking into the httpd.conf in IFS they point to they listen on port 80 and 2020. So I started these instanced for testing.

The service on port 2020 is restricted to */webaccess* and gives error 500 when trying to access that one. There are no corresponding entries in the error log but *webaccess-plugin.log* shows these entries:

```
ws_common: websphereGetStream: Failed to connect to app server on host 'localhost', OS err=3425                               
ws_common: websphereExecute: Failed to create the stream                                                                      
ws_common: websphereHandleRequest: Failed to execute the transaction to 'webaccess 1'on host 'localhost'; will try another one
ws_common: websphereWriteRequestReadResponse: Failed to find an app server to handle this request                             
ESI: getResponse: failed to get response: rc = 2                                                                              
ws_common: websphereHandleRequest: Failed to handle request
```

Comparing `GO LICPGM` menu, option 10 and 11 to list installed components and list installable components, I can see that there's no *IBM Dev Kit for Java* installed, as well as no flavor of available Java SE. All *IBM I Access* components are installed, though.

Doing some research, I found [a clue](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-enable-admin2-ibm-navigator-i-and-admin5-jobs-ibm-i-access-mobile-ssltls-communications-ibm-web-administration-i-console) that 2004 is called the *ADMIN2*-Instance but I can't find a reference to it in *QUSRSYS/QATMHINSTC*.

Research also [pointed me](http://newsolutions.de/forum-systemi-as400-i5-iseries/threads/20691-IBM-Navigator-for-i-funktioniert-nicht-mehr) to a path buried deep within the IFS which shows that basically at least *some* stuff for admin2 is installed. The log file within there is empty.

`wrkobj qlwi* *all` shows a bunch of objects, also a *qlwiadm* program object. So I think, basic stuff is installed.

**I suspect that I've missed to install certain components. But which?** Can't find a reference to anything websphere'ish in the installable licpgm list.

Second, **maybe I'm facing two distinct problems?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin instances *require* the installation of the OS media supplied java development kit and also one of the OS media supplied java runtime environments.

That in turn requires PASE to be installed also.

After installing and (re)starting the http server via strtcpsvr, Port 2004 ist finally open.